# Php line break in csv

Tags: php, csv, line, break

I am working for hours of how to line break in my csv with php, but could not accomplish anything.

I built a csv with data from the database as an information.

I basically have this:

```
$company = $row['COL 4']." ".$row['COL 5']." ".$row['COL 6']." ".$row['COL 7'];
$company = str_replace("\n", " ", $company);
$company = str_replace("\r", " ", $company);
```

As you can see I try to line break after each rows, but it doesnt work.

The csv looks something like this now

`Google Microsoft Apple Sony`

but it shall line break and look like this:

`Google 
Microsoft 
Apple 
Sony`

Comment: `str_replace()` uses the arguments the other way round. Right now you are replacing a new line with a space.

Comment: Use `PHP_EOL` for new line

Comment: you can also use '\n';

Comment: `$company = str_replace(" ", "\n", $company);`

Comment: Thanks, I tried it out but did not work property.

Answer (score 0):

```
$fp = fopen('php://memory', 'w+');

// replace $rows with your iterator
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    fputcsv($fp, $row);
}

fseek($fp, 0);

$csv = '';

while (!feof($fp)) {
    $csv .= fread($fp, 1024 * 8);
}

echo $csv;
```

Comment: I take it you are trying to write CSV as a string, normally this is done to a file with `fputcsv`, but for this example we're opening a virtual file and writing to it.  The problem with your code is it doesn't account for delimiter escaping.  so if one of your columns has a space in it, it will split into 2 columns.  `fputcsv` handles most edge cases for you.

Comment: Why don't you add this explanation to your answer? Currently your answer contains 0 explanation which makes it worthless. That's what I wanted to point out.